# embed member information in another member's profile

Tags: embeds, zoo-visitor

I am using zoo visitor, safecracker and solspace user to enable a site member to act as an agent and register other client members to the site.
These new members are linked to the agent via a hidden text field that is filled during the registration process with the agent's member_id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="agent_id" id="agent_id" value="{exp:user:is_mine     member_id="{member_id}"}{member_id}{/exp:user:is_mine}">
```

I now need to show some of the agent's info in the client's template. (agent name and logo)
I'm sure I could use an embed of some sort but I'm not quite sure where to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the agent signs up a member write the member id of the agent to a custom member field of the user.

Then when outputting details of the user, you can use an embed of some sort and pass the agent's member ID to it something like;

Assuming {agent_id} is the name of the custom profile field in which the agent's member id is stored.

```
embed('includes/_agentinfo' agentid="{agent_id}')
```